# Assign an already made attribute to all of magento's attribute sets

Tags: php, magento, attributes

after endless searching on the net, about this i finally gave up on the matter.
i'i trying to make a script for magento ( in my case 1.6.2.0 ) to have an already made attribute (in my case "techpage") to be programmatically assign to all attributes sets in the "General" group.

Goog planning from the beginning saves a lot of time, i'm learning this the hard way!

Can someone pls tell me what i'm doing wrong ?

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app('default'); // Change default to whatever store you want to run

$model=Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup','core_setup');
$attributeId=$model->getAttribute('catalog_product','techpage');

$allAttributeSetIds=$model->getAllAttributeSetIds('catalog_product');
foreach ($allAttributeSetIds as $attributeSetId) {
try{
$attributeGroupId=$model-    >getAttributeGroup('catalog_product',$attributeSetId,'General');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
$attributeGroupId=$model->getDefaultArrtibuteGroupId('catalog/product',$attributeSetId);
}
$model-   >addAttributeToSet('catalog_product',$attributeSetId,$attributeGroupId,$attributeId);
}
?>
```

When i run this in my browser, the damn thins spits out

> "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException'

with message

> 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails "

I'm not exactly what you call the "sharpest tool in the shed" when it comes to php and magento, but in my searches i have found tons of newbies like me searching for the same thing, and no answer to this dilema.

any help on this would greatly increese my nightly sleep time :) and i bet others too,
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, your variable $attributeId is not numeric but an array. 
Use this little fix and it should work.

```
$model->addAttributeToSet('catalog_product', $attributeSetId, $attributeGroupId, $attributeId['attribute_id']);
```

Do you use a debugger? You could have solved this problem in minutes with xdebug.

Comment: thanks so much for the answer! the attribute id for techpage is 1457 , i edited the script but i still get the same thing.

Comment: try to enable MySQL logging and look for the insert/update script that is generated, analyze it and it may give you an idea. I've just tried your script and it worked - I added a test attribute to every catalog attribute set in my test shop.

Comment: really ? :)) it worked ? i'm suprised :) unfortunately can't do that because my host does not allow admin acces

Comment: <?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app('default'); // Change default to whatever store you want to run

$model=Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup','core_setup');
$attributeId=$model->getAttribute('catalog_product','test');

$allAttributeSetIds=$model->getAllAttributeSetIds('catalog_product');
foreach ($allAttributeSetIds as $attributeSetId) {
try{
$attributeGroupId=$model->getAttributeGroup('catalog_product',$attributeSetId,'General');
}

Comment: catch(Exception $e)
{
$attributeGroupId=$model->getDefaultArrtibuteGroupId('catalog/product',$attributeSetId);
}
$model->addAttributeToSet('catalog_product',$attributeSetId,$attributeGroupId,$attributeId['attribute_id']);
}
?>

Comment: damn stil get the "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`rraz4580_raza`.`eav_entity_attribute`, CONSTRAINT `FK_EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ON)' in /home/rraz4580/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0 /home/rraz4580/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /home/rraz4580/public_html etc

Comment: <?php 
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento umask(0); 
Mage::app('default'); // Change default to whatever store you want to run 
$model=Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup','core_setup'); 
$attributeId=$model->getAttribute('catalog_product','techpage'); 
$allAttributeSetIds=$model->getAllAttributeSetIds('catalog_product'); 
foreach ($allAttributeSetIds as $attributeSetId) 
{

Comment: try{ $attributeGroupId=$model->getAttributeGroup('catalog_product',$attributeSetId,'General'); }

catch(Exception $e) { 
$attributeGroupId=$model->getDefaultArrtibuteGroupId('catalog/product',$attributeSetId); } 
$model->addAttributeToSet('catalog_product',$attributeSetId,$attributeGroupId,$attributeId['1457']); } 
?>

Comment: $a‌​ttributeId['1457'] - is wrong! This array does not have this key! If you want to set the attribute id explicitly just call $model->addAttributeToSet('catalog_product',$attributeSetId,$attributeGroupId,1457);

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it works with no problem. You're the man :)) you have just bought me some extra sleep time. :))) No really! thank for taking the time !

Answer (score 0):

The exception is a database constraint exception. You should look at the catalog_product table and see if it has any constraints that the above code is (indirectly) violating.